# Using Bash to Search Column in a csv file, find it in a txt file, then if found, output Column 1 and 2 from first csv to second csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep, txt

I have 2 .csv files and 1 txt file. fileA.csv has info like this:

```
Column1             Column2

Row1 Column1 Info   Row1 Column2 Data 1 xyz
Row2 Column1 Info   Row2 Column2 Data
Row3 Column1 Info   Row3 Column2 More Data 2 XYZ ABC
```

EDIT: This is a csv, so the columns are separated by commas when cat'ed out in a terminal.

fileB.txt is just a generic .txt file with info like this

```
Row1 Column2 Info = XYZ

Row3 Column2 Info = ABC
```

What I want to do is search each row of fileA.csv's Column 2, in all of fileB.txt. Then, if a match is found, output both fileA.csv's Columns(1 and 2) to either Column 1 of fileC.csv or if syntactically easier, column 1 and column 2 respectively

The desired output into fileC.csv using the test info above would be

```
Column1


Row1 Column1 Info Row1   Column2 Info = XYZ

Row3 Column1 Info Row3   Column2 Info = ABC
```

or if it's easier syntactically

```
Column1                   Column2

Row1 Column1 Info Row1    Row1 Column2 Info = XYZ

Row3 Column1 Info Row3    Row3 Column2 Info = ABC
```

I've tried using awk and grep, but am not familiar enough with Bash scripting to search info from a specific column in fileA, search a txt file for it, then output both columns from fileA into fileC.csv

BTW, this is NOT a homework assignment :)

Comment: Are those tab-separated files? There are no commas, so there's no easy way to detect columns. Is using a DB (applicable to and much more appropriate for a bajillion extremely similar questions on this site) out of the question?

Comment: No, it's a csv, so separated commas when cat'ed out in a terminal. Updated Original question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, yeah, if this were a database, SQL could probably make this relatively easy but for the scope of this, a database would be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maube this will work:

```
awk '{print $4, $5, $6 > "test-fileA"}' fileA.csv;
grep -o -Ff test-fileA fileB.txt > test-fileB; 
grep -n -Ff test-fileB test-fileA | cut -f1 | xargs echo > test-fileC;
awk 'NR==FNR { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i] = $i; next } (FNR in a) {print $0 > "fileC.csv" }' test-fileC fileA.csv; rm test-file*
```

1. First line print result from Column2 into temporary file 'test-fileA' so we can later use
2. We compare 'test-fileA' with fileB.txt  and cut result to test-fileB;
3. Then we compare files that we created to get result what line to use for last command; We need to print result lines from fileA.csv into fileC.csv
4. We get result comparing lines that match in AWK and print it to fileC.csv; Then we remove all temporary files that were created;

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference, but in the second line of your code, you have:

"file-b.csv"

This would be the actual file we need to search through, but in our case, it's a normal .txt file, not a .csv file. Would that make a difference in your code?

Comment: @MM3113 there is no difference, I change just file names like you asked, it is done. Try it and tell me results

Comment: Ok, so I'm going line by line of your code. The first line looks to grab the 4th-6th elements of that row, not the entire column itself. The only problem with this is column 2 of fileA.csv has varying degrees of data. row 1 column 2 might have "this data here" wheras row 3 column two might have "that data way over there".

So I think we need to do 
```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2 > "test-fileA"}' fileA.csv

I'll post more as I run through it. I will also update the original question to reflect this. TY!

Comment: Looks like it worked! I'm a little fuzzy on the "cut" part of your 3rd line of code. You're using a delimiter of ':' , but neither test-fileA nor test-fileB has colons(:) in them. How does cut know to extract the numbers and put them into test-fileC?

Comment: @MM3113 You are right, we don't need delimiter in cut. I will remove it from code, my bad..